# Given a string, how do I compare the characters to see if there are duplicates?

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I'm trying to compare characters in a given string to see if there are duplicates, and if there are I was to remove the two characters to reduce the string to as small at possible. eg. `("ttyyzx")` would equal to `("zx")`

I've tried converting the characters in an array and then using an `#each_with_index` to iterate over the characters.

```
arr = ("xxyz").split("")

  arr.each_with_index do |idx1, idx2|
    if idx1[idx2] == idx1[idx2 + 1]
      p idx1[idx2]
      p idx1[idx2 + 1]
    end
  end
```

At this point I just wan to be able to print the next character in the array within the loop so I know I can move on to the next step, but no matter what code I use it will only print out the first character `"x"`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What happens on a string like `"aba"`? Do we get `"b"` or `"aba"`?

Comment: It is much easier to write code when you don't have to break your brain trying to remember what is in which variable. `idx1` being a character and `idx2` being an index is _not ideal_. You are also printing two characters per loop iteration, which can't be right (imagine nothing needs to be removed - you'd be printing double the characters in the string). And finally, you're printing when two characters are _the same_, not when they are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While amadan's and user's solution definitely solve the problem I felt like writing a solution closer to the OP's attempt:

```
def clean(string)
return string if string.length == 1

array = string.split('')
array.select.with_index do |value, index|
array[index - 1] != value && array[index + 1] != value
end.join
end
```

Here are a few examples:

```
puts clean("aaaaabccccdeeeeeefgggg")
#-> bdf
puts clean("m")
#-> m
puts clean("ttyyzx")
#-> zx
puts clean("aab")
#-> b
```

The method makes use of the fact that the characters are sorted and in case there are duplicates, they are either before or after the character that's being checked by the select method. The method is slower than the solutions posted above, but as OP mentioned he does not yet work with hashes yet I though this might be useful.

Comment: This is exactly how I was trying to attempt it, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! Keep in mind, naming strings `string` or arrays `array` isn't the best way to go.The only reason I did it here it to make it a bit clearer what's going on.

Answer (score 5):

To only keep the unique characters (ggorlen's answer is "b"): count all characters, find only those that appear once. We rely on Ruby's Hash producing keys in insertion order.

```
def keep_unique_chars(str)
  str.each_char.
      with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |element, counts| counts[element] += 1 }.
      select { |_, count| count == 1 }.
      keys.
      join
end
```

To remove adjacent dupes only (ggorlen's answer is "aba"): a regular expression replacing adjacent repetitions is probably the go-to method.

```
def remove_adjacent_dupes(str)
  str.gsub(/(.)\1+/, '')
end
```

Without regular expressions, we can use `slice_when` to cut the array when the character changes, then drop the groups that are too long. One might think a `flatten` would be required before `join`, but `join` doesn't care:

```
def remove_adjacent_dupes_without_regexp(str)
  str.each_char.
      slice_when { |prev, curr| prev != curr }.
      select { |group| group.size == 1 }.
      join
end
```

Comment: Can you explain how to do this with a simple iterator, I don't really know how to use hashes, yet. Thanks. To answer ggorlens question and just so everyone is on the same page lets say the string characters are always given in alphabetical order, eg. "aabbcdd" would be reduced to "c", thank you.

Comment: I like that your first solution works because newer versions of Ruby remember the order in which the keys were added. The `('')` argument to `join` is not needed afaik.

Comment: Hashes are pretty much same as arrays, except they are indexed by almost anything, not by successive integers like arrays. This is a good opportunity to learn about hashes! :) However, if the characters are sorted as you suggest, the regexp solution  (second one) is the one you need. I will add a third one that doesn't use regexp.

Comment: @spickermann I think you are right - JS defaults to commas, Ruby to nothing, and it's a bit of a pain in the behind to remember :P

Answer (score 0):

If speed is not an issue,

```
require 'set'
...
Set.new(("xxyz").split("")).to_a.join # => xyz
```

Making it a `Set` removes duplicates.

The OP does not want to remove duplicates and keep just a single copy, but remove all characters completely from occurring more than once. So here is a new approach, again compact, but not fast:

```
"xxyz".split('').sort.join.gsub(/(.)\1+/,'')
```

The idea is to sort the the letters; hence, identical letters will be joined together. The regexp `/(.)\1+/` describes a repetition of a letter.

Comment: OP wants to remove anything repeating, not just extra copies. Note OP's example: `"ttyyzx"` needs to become `"zx"`, not `"tyzx"` as your code makes it.

Comment: Since OP stipulates that the letters are sorted already, `sort` is unnecessary. If it was not the case, then `sort` would have changed the order of the letters in the string. And `gsub(/(.)\1+/,'')` part is correct, as I wrote it in my answer over an hour ago :P